# Elasticbeanstalk with Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

When I try to create new environment using docker container shows the error message, using `eb create` or from `aws console`, yes, if I just try to create an environment from web console the same messages appears.

```
Unknown or duplicate parameter: WSGIPath
```

I've followed this tutorial http://victorlin.me/posts/2014/11/26/running-docker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk

whats's wrong?

is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved, there was a folder called .ebextensions in project root, just remove it and the deploy worked!